# Have trouble to use URLConnection to get the original web page source code when it redirected to another page automatically

Tags: java, urlconnection

When I opened the webpage in browser, I can successfully reach the web page. However when I tired to get the source code of the webpage in Java online, the web page automatically redirected to another page and so I can only got the source code of the new web page in my program. Is there any way I can break such redirection thing in java?

Thx a lot.

The following is the part of fetching the source code in my program.

The destination web page is an online community web page (sth. like Facebook), which belongs to the largest internet company (Baidu) in China.

When you run the following program, you'll find that the web page source code posted in the console is not the code which you can get from the browser. And the posted source code in the console is almost same with what you can find in the following web page,
http://www.baidu.com/search/ressafe.html?q=%E5%AE%AB%E5%B4%8E%E9%AA%8F%E5%90%A7&url=http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%B9%AC%C6%E9%BF%A5

which shows the web page is redirected.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class URLConnectTest {

    public static final String s = "%B9%AC%C6%E9%BF%A5";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL u = new URL("http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=" + s);
        URLConnection yc = u.openConnection();

        /* I've ever tried to reset the UA, which doesn't work.
        yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.16 Safari/534.24");
        */

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this behaviour across all the types of browsers?

Comment: Sorry about the confusing part of my question. There are something wrong when I tried to fetch the source code in Java, not in browser.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTPURLConnection` follows HTTP redirections automatically, if you want to disable it, call `HTTPURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)`.

Comment: Yes, that was expected and I thought that was what you wanted(you said you wanted to **break the redirection thing** in your question). Now it looks like that you don't like the result, then you probably need to describe your problem better and attach some code.

Comment: Have uploaded some more details, including my code and the web page I wanted to get the source code.

Comment: OK, I tried opening that page in Chrome, and with the Chrome extension `Redirect Path`, I didn't see any redirects, so I guessed it must be something related to cookies. Indeed, when I set the cookie for the request, the page is properly(no redirects) loaded. PS. For getting cookies, visit that page in Chrome and from `Developer Tools` you can see the request/response headers.

Comment: Thx a lot... I just clear all my cookies in my computer and everything is Okay now.